# How can I debug a dieing jupyter notebook ipython kernel?

Tags: python, debugging, jupyter-notebook, ipython

When running my jupyter notebooks, the ipython kernel (Python 3.8, Anaconda) keeps dieing and being restarted.

I want to find what causes it to misbehave. Sadly, I can find no debugging information other than the kernel is dead and restarted.

How can I find more verbose information which may help with *post mortem* analysis? Is there any error log or something like that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you start Jupyter from a console with this command (may from the Anaconda terminal):

```
jupyter notebook --debug
```

then it will print extended logging messages. You may also pipe those messages into a separate `logfile.txt`  using

```
jupyter notebook --debug > logfile.txt 2>&1
```

Answer (score -1):

Can you try uninstalling all of:

```
ipykernel
ipython
jupyter_client
jupyter_core
traitlets
ipython_genutils
```

And then install again. If you're doing this inside a conda env, it might be easiest to create a new environment and start from scratch. Also, if you're going to install with conda, run conda clean -tipsy to clean up conda caches before you start

Comment: That may help if the issue is with the environment, but so far everything worked well and I did not update it, thus it is more likely that the problem originates from my code, thus I'd like to access more information about the kernel death.

Comment: @abukaj "thus it is more likely that the problem originates from my code".  Then update your question with a [mcve] that causes the crash and you'll be far more likely to get help.

Comment: Remember to provide source of your answer https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1892#issuecomment-260403964

Comment: @MarkTolonen I wish the issue were reproducible. The same notebook sometimes crashes and sometimes works fine.